# Optimisation and strict aliasing

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

My question is regarding a code fragment, such as below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double a = -50;
    std::cout << a << "\n";
    uint8_t* b = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&a);
    b[7] &= 0x7F;
    std::cout << a << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I can tell I am not breaking any rules and everything is well defined (as noted below I forgot that `uint8_t` is not allowed to alias other types). There is some implementation defined behavior going on, but for the purpose of this question I don't think that is relevant.

I would expect this code to print `-50`, then `50` on systems where the `double` follows the IEEE standard, is `8` bytes long and is stored in little endian format. Now the question is. Does the compiler guarantee that this happens. More specifically, turning on optimisations can the compiler optimise away the middle `b[7]`, either explicitly or implicitly, by simply keeping `a` in a register through the whole function. The second one obviously could be solved by specifying `volatile double a`, but is that needed?

Edit: As an a note I (mistakenly) remembered that `uint8_t` was required to be an alias for `unsigned char`, but indeed the standard does not specify such. I have also written the question in a way that, yes the compiler can ahead of time know everything here, but modified to

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double a;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << a << "\n";
    unsigned char* b = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&a);
    b[7] &= 0x7F;
    std::cout << a << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

one can see where the problem might arise. Here the strict aliasing rule is no longer violated, and `a` is not a compile time constant. Richard Critten's comment however is curious if the aliased data can be examined, but not written, is there a way one can set individual bytes, while still following the standard?

Comment: A) the compiler sees you taking the address of `a` and accessing it through b and B) uint8_t is often a typedef to char and char* may alias anything. So 2 reasons why this has to read a from memory again for the second cout..

Comment: _"...AliasedType is std::byte, (since C++17) char, or unsigned char: this permits __examination__ of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes...."_ - examination only (not write) and `uint8_t` is not in the list of allow types https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Probably not `char`, but likely `unsigned char` instead. Same allowance applies to it as well though.

Comment: @RichardCritten You can do `static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::uint8_t, unsigned char>)`, and then you have a guarantee that either it is on that list, or you are informed that it isn't.

Comment: `uint8_t` is not a character type and cannot be used for aliasing other types. Use `unsigned char or `std::byte`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. `uint8_t is not a character type` Not quite so. `std::uint8_t` is technically not guaranteed to be a character type, but it *may* be a character type. It happens to be a character type in all language implementations that I've ever encountered, excluding those where `std::uint8_t` is not defined at all. Using `unsigned char` or `std::byte` is probably better, but it would also require asserting that the size of byte is what is expected considering the logic relies on that.

Comment: @RichardCritten cppreference is not a primary source. Only the C++ standard is. As far as I can tell, the standard doesn't prohibit such writing.

Comment: Of course, if you want to pull stunts like this safely you can always compile that file with `-fno-strict-aliasing`.  Just sayin'

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. which is why it's just a comment - digging through the standard at the moment.

Comment: @eerorika Are you sure about std::byte? That's an enum class with storage char. From cppreference.com: *it is not a character type*. I believe that is one of the benefits of byte that it does in fact not alias.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow `Are you sure about std::byte?` I'm sure that `std::byte` is allowed to alias other types which is why it could probably be a good option to use in this case. It is not a character type unlike `unsigned char` (aka `std::uint8_t` in most systems) which is a character type.

Comment: @eerorika https://godbolt.org/z/xf493ee7M Strangely `std::byte` aliases but `enum class byte : unsigned char {};` does not alias. Compiler bug?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow The exceptional property of `std::byte` is not *because* it is such enum. That exception is granted explicitly to `std::byte` alone (and narrow character types); not to all enums that are similar. Seems correct to me.

Comment: @eerorika Yeah, I see the wording in the specs giving byte special powers. Damn confusing though to have a type behave differently when you copy it 1:1 to somewhere else.

Comment: As @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem has pointed out, cppreference is not a primary source and as the question is tagged [language-lawyer] I need to back this statement up with a quote from the standard (if I can find one).

Comment: @RichardCritten It seems the standard does not make such a claim. [It says](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11): "If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue whose type is not similar to one of the following types the behavior is undefined [...]", where access is defined as: "read or modify the value of an object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> More specifically, turning on optimisations can the compiler optimise away the middle b[7], either explicitly or implicitly, by simply keeping a in a register through the whole function.

The compiler can generate the double value 50 as a constant, and pass that directly to the output function. `b` can be optimised away completely. Like most optimisation, this is due to the as-if rule:

> [intro.abstract]
>
> The semantic descriptions in this document define a parameterized nondeterministic abstract machine.
> This document places no requirement on the structure of conforming implementations.
> In particular, they need not copy or emulate the structure of the abstract machine.
> Rather, conforming implementations are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine as explained below.

---

> The second one obviously could be solved by specifying `volatile double a`

That would prevent the optimisation, which would generally be considered to be the opposite of a solution.

---

> Does the compiler guarantee that [50 is printed].

You didn't mention what compiler you are asking about. I'm going to assume that you mean whether the standard guarantees this. It doesn't guarantee that universally. You are relying on several assumptions about the implementation:

- If `sizeof(double) < 8`, then you access the object outside of its bounds, and behaviour of the program is undefined.
- If `std::uint8_t` is not an a type alias of `unsigned char`, then it isn't allowed to alias `double`, and the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Given the assumptions hold and thus behviour is well-defined, then the second output will be of a `double` value that is like -50, but whose most significant bit(s from 8th forward) of the byte at position 7 will have been set to 0. In case of little endian IEEE-754 representation, that value would be 50. `volatile` is not needed to guarantee this, and it won't add a guarantee in case the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: While not specifically spelled out in the question it should be clear that the question was whether the compiler could print -50 both times. Gcc and clang in fact optimize away the b but keep the effect. The generated code contains constants for `-50` and `50` that get printed.

Comment: I postulate that the implementation does have `sizeof(double) == 8` and uses the IEEE-754 representation in little endian format. I misremembered the definition of `uint8_t`, so 'unsigned char' is what I'd replace it to. I tried not to include issues with strict aliasing